# Compatibility of ndb models with WTForms

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2, wtforms, app-engine-ndb

Tech Stack: **ndb models**, **WTForms**, **webapp2** 
I was experimenting with the WTForms extension to appengine db models.

I had a simple db schema:

```
class Autho(ndb.Models):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Notes(ndb.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    author = db.KeyProperty()
```

and then a simple form definition form WTForms, in the handlers as per their documentation:

```
from wtforms.ext.appengine.db import model_form

def get(self, slug):
        form = model_form(Author)()
        self.render_template('form.html', {'form': form})
```

This raises an Attribute Error line 411 [here](https://bitbucket.org/simplecodes/wtforms/src/a5f9e30260cc/wtforms/ext/appengine/db.py) `props = model.properties()`

Please let me know, if this can be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used WTForms, but it seems to be incompatible with NDB -- "model.properties()" is an old db idiom.  Maybe the WTForms author will consider adding support for NBD?

Comment: If WTforms doesn't work, are there any other html form libraries that work with ndb?

Comment: Check this: Added support for ndb https://bitbucket.org/madfarmer/wtforms/src/759476ef4835/wtforms/ext/appengine/ndb.py

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate. 
It's a ndb boilerplate with a basic (not so basic for me) implementation of user authentication that accepts federated login. It uses WTForms thoroughly. The guys that created it are very well reachable and the boilerplate is constantly maintained and updated. Worth a look, it helps a lot with basic patterns.

Comment: It's advised not to supply link only answers, because links tend to die overtime.